# Ошибка в python с токеном

Tags: python

Объясните тупому.При запуске бота возникает ошибка...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\data\config.py", line 10, in <module>
    BOT_TOKEN = read_config ['settings']['token'].strip()
```

Токен в конфиге указан и так и сяк пытался исправить но ничего...[image: скриншот]

Сам конфиг...

```
# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-
[settings]
token = 9999999999999999999999999999999999999
admin_id = 9999999999
admin = 9999999999999
shopadmin_id = 99999999999
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Покажите метод configParser.ConfigParser()

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, что выдаст `print(read_config.sections())`, похоже у вас в `settings.ini` не то, что вы думаете. Либо, как вариант, где-то у вас закралась русская буква среди английских - или в конфиге, или в коде программы. И код нужно прикладывать к вопросу в виде текста. И ошибку нужно добавлять целиком, а не выбранные вами строки.

Comment: @RottenRat Это же стандартная библиотека для чтения конфигов

Comment: Сделай принт на config.sections()

Comment: # - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-
import sqlite3
import configparser
import json


read_config = configparser.ConfigParser()
print(read_config.sections())

BOT_TOKEN = read_config['settings']['token'].strip()
PATH_DATABASE = 'tgbot/data/database.db'
PATH_LOGS = 'tgbot/data/logs.log'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

Сделал вот так и все равно та же ошибка.Или я не туда добавил sections?

Comment: А куда делся `read_config.read('settings.ini')`? После него нужно печать секций добавить и показать нам что она выведет. И код ваш добавьте в сам вопрос, вы его можете редактировать.